# theata limits on polar plots only one-sided

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a polar plot, for half directions.  I'm using the `ax.set_thetalim` and can't seem to figure out how to use the "other half of the pie" (ie from 342 to 162 including 90 degrees, excluding 270).  I've tried to flip the lims to no avail.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
lims2 = [342, 162]
ax.set_thetalim(np.deg2rad(lims1))
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
```

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
lims2 = [162,342]
ax.set_thetalim(np.deg2rad(lims1))
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the other half of the polar plot, you would want to set the limit from -18 to 162.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(11,6), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')

lims1 =  [342, 162]
lims2 =  [-18, 162]

ax1.set_thetalim(np.deg2rad(lims1))
ax2.set_thetalim(np.deg2rad(lims2))

plt.show()
```

[image]